# Candlestick/Financial Charts in Ruby

Tags: ruby, charts

Are there any good libraries available for plotting [candlestick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) and other types of financial charts in Ruby?  I saw [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089307/financial-charts-graphs-in-ruby-or-python) from over a year ago. The presented options that fit my needs from that post were Python, however.

EDIT:

One requirement is that I need real-time charts, updating multiple times a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google chart API supports [candlestick charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/compound_charts.html#candlestick_charts), among other things.

There are a few gems that automate this: [googlecharts](http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/), [gchartrb](http://gchartrb.rubyforge.org/). I haven't used them but they look like a good first cut.

Here's a quick example from the docs:

[image: Candlestick example:]

Comment: I need real-time charts, updating multiple times per second.  I thought Google Charts was static.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: I suppose you could make multiple queries to change the view but as far as I know there is a one-to-one mapping of URLs to images.

Comment: html/javascript timed reload? also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775836/ruby-charting-library and http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/graphing.html might be interesting to you